# How to check if an object's fields have changed in Python?

Tags: python, hash

I have class like this:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I create an instance of this class by:

```
p1 = Point(5, 10)
```

I want to know if any field of this class was changed. I suppose that there can be some kind of hash function which results I can compare.

For example, in bash I can write `md5sum <<<"string"`, `md5sum <<<"string"` in order to get `x`, `y` respectively. Then I can compare `x` and `y` to find out if they are different or not.

Is there an analogous method which works on Python's object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve that by overriding `__setattr__` class method.

```
In[6]: class Point(object):
           def __init__(self, x, y):
               self.x = x
               self.y = y
               self._changed = False

           def __setattr__(self, key, value):
               if key != '_changed':
                   self._changed = True
               super(Point, self).__setattr__(key, value)

           def is_changed(self):
               return self._changed

In[7]: p = Point(2,3)
In[8]: p.is_changed()
Out[8]: False
In[9]: p.x = 23
In[10]: p.is_changed()
Out[10]: True
```

Comment: Quick note, this doesn't work when one of the attributes is mutable (like with a list). When the constructor sets a list and that same list gets appended something, it will not be detected by the __setattr__ function

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to hash all the instance variables to detect changes:

```
>>> p1 = Point(5, 10)
>>> h = hash(frozenset(vars(p1).items()))        # Record a hash checksum
>>> h == hash(frozenset(vars(p1).items()))       # Check for changes 
True
>>> p1.x += 1                                    # Change the object data
>>> h == hash(frozenset(vars(p1).items()))       # Check for changes
False
```

The technique uses:

- [vars()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to access the instance dictionary
- [items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to get the key and values as a list of tuples
- [frozenset()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-frozenset) to make a hashable unordered
- [hash()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) to compute the checksum

Comment: I tried this on a function: def test_function(a, b, c, num_sims):
    return pd.DataFrame({'a':[a]*num_sims, 'b':[b]*num_sims, 'c':[c]*num_sims}) and it just gives me unhashable type dict